# Using JSON transformer in jdbi bulk insert

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbi

let's say I have a postgres table with 2 columns.

```
id: text
name: jsonb
```

Now I'm using jdbi to do a batch insert

```
@SqlBatch("INSERT INTO something (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)"
void batchUpdate(@BindBean List<SomeObject> someObjectList);
```

SomeObject looks like this:

```
public class SomeObject{
    String id;
    SomeNameObject name;

   //constructor and so on
}
```

So basically I want to bulk insert a bean which contains an object that needs to be transformed to json before inserting. Is there a way to do this with jdbi while using bulk inserts?

Thanks

Comment: For reference, the solution is using rosetta.
https://github.com/HubSpot/Rosetta/blob/master/FEATURES.md

Answer (score 1):

Honestly what worked for me, was to use a string and cast it in the query
so something like the following:

```
public class SomeObject{
    String id;
    // SomeNameObject name; // change this to a string
    String name;

   //constructor and so on
}
```

and for the query

```
@SqlBatch("INSERT INTO something (id, name) VALUES (:id, CAST(:name as jsonb))" // add cast here
void batchUpdate(@BindBean List<SomeObject> someObjectList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below worked for me.
The Json annotation on the instance property itself did not work for me.So had to to use on the getter.
The docs are [here](https://jdbi.org/#jdbi3-json)

```
public class SomeObject{
    String id;
    SomeNameObject name;
    @Json
    public getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

   //constructor and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Rosetta documentation, I think you should be able achieve this by using `@BindWithRosetta` &  `@StoredAsJson` annotation.

```
@SqlBatch("INSERT INTO something (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)"
void batchUpdate(@BindWithRosetta List<SomeObject> someObjectList);

public class SomeObject{
  String id;
  @StoredAsJson
  SomeNameObject name;

  //constructor and so on
}
```